# ¿Como inserto un logo dentro de mi <header> sin que este arruine el tamaño de mi cabecera?

Tags: html, css, html5

Al querer insertarle un logo de la empresa a una pagina web, me cambia el tamaño de mi cabecera.

¿Que consejos me pueden dar de como poner un logo centrado en una cabecera?

Mi idea es que este el logo en la cabecera y que este logo se pueda clickear para regresar a la pagina principal.

Mi código es el siguiente.

```
      <div class="logo-nav-container">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="img/logo header.png" class="logo" alt="my logo">
        </a>
        <nav class="navigation">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="dogs.html">Dogs</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>  
    </header>
```

Comment: Podrías usar CSS para dar un tamaño máximo al contenedor de la imagen y además hacer que la imagen se adapte a dicho contenedor. Es una idea. Por otro lado, te invito a leer [ask]. Tu pregunta parece basada en opiniones, ya que estás pidiendo *consejos*. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Eso se realiza con css, puedes agregarlo directamente a la etiqueta html aunque lo ideal es agregar un archivo css externo.

En el ejemplo la imagen es de un tamano 200*300 pero en la etiqueta style se redimensiona a 150px * 120px, coloca la medida que consideres adecuada.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="logo-nav-container">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" style="width: 150px; height: 120px;" class="logo" alt="my logo">
    </a>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="dogs.html">Dogs</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```